# PHP5.6 Unable to load dynamic library (php_pdo_mysql)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I recently upgraded PHP 5.5.9 to PHP 5.6 by doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

But when I run PHP through CLI I get the following warning everytime:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

How to fix this? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, apparently I had uncommented `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` in my `php.ini`. Of course this wouldn't work on Ubuntu.